# MYSQL licence for this exact situation

Tags: java, mysql, licensing, mysql-connector

Can i use MYSQL community version if i am developing an online game , where the server application(in the server only) uses MySQL and MySQL connector java (gpl) to function , but the client application(distributed to end-users) don't use MySQL , do i still need to buy MYSQL ?

Comment: It depends on if your game will be paid or free

Comment: The game itself is paid but the client application doesnt contain MYSQL and doesnt connect to a mysql server , only server does(which is not shipped or sent to client)

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about licensing issues and not about programming. Ask the vendor or a lawyer.

Comment: I dont have lawyers here in my country who will understand this. xD

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server application does not link to the MySQL server itself, and does not need to be open-source or available to all, in order to use MySQL community edition.

However, if you *distribute* any program or client that uses the MySQL *client library* then that program must be open-source and easily available. This does not apply to your server code as it is not distributed.

Comment: My server application connects to MYSQL through MYSQL connector both are GPL licensed , and the server code contains ofcourse the MYSQL Java connector library to connect to the MYSQL server but the server itself is not distributed or given to the client , the client only pays for the online game(client application) and not server

Comment: There is no problem as long as you are not distributing the server application.

Comment: @Omarshaaban no problem, please mark the check mark next to the answer if it helped you satisfactorily.